# How to display "Twint response" on html page? As the data is displayed only on command promt

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am beginner in django, twint
I am trying to write API call with query parameters for displaying Twint response on html page or postman, but the extracted data is displayed in command prompt. 
Please guide me through this.

I am using Updated version of twint, Python 3.7, Django 3.0, windows 10

Below is my code

views.py

```
class UserName(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        return self.username(request,request.query_params)
    def username(self, request, result):
        c = twint.Config()
        c.Username = "MotaJyothsna"
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        result = twint.run.Search(c)
        return Response(result)
```

[image: Output is displayed on Command prompt , but not in browser]

Comment: Can you show what's in result variable?

Comment: @Charnel I am getting below error when i don't mention username in the code

C:\Users\twint_project\twitter_project\twitter_project\urls.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Django version 3.0.1, using settings 'twitter_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noData'items_html'
 
When i use username in code am getting all the tweets in Command prompt

Comment: First thing is that I'm not sure what's result return (data format). Next, you aren't showed what you get if you try to make a request to this endpoint. Last thing - you're starting event loop (why?) and then getting the result from twint - possibly that result is never "awaited" in Django thread that handles the request.

Comment: @Charnel I have edited the question with output, please check, and i used event loop as am getting an error without it, like below
File "C:\Users\jyo27\OneDrive\Documents\assignment\training\twint_project\twitter_project\twitter_app\views.py", line 21, in username
    result = twint.run.Search(c)
  File "C:\Users\jyo27\Envs\env1\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 288, in Search
    run(config, callback)

Comment: File "C:\Users\jyo27\Envs\env1\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 209, in run
    get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main(callback))
  File "c:\users\jyo27\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /user/
Exception Value: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.

Comment: Try to move event loop creation before you call twint.Config() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get the output on a html page using following code.

```
def username(request):
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Username = "Twitter"
    c.Limit = 20
    c.Hide_output = True
    c.Output = "data.html"
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    twint.run.Search(c)
    return render(request,data.html)
```